# Breakage of Tikz fill operation on cycle path with let and node reference?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc} % \widthof
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagecolor{yellow!15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (neL0) at (1,4) {};
\node (neRM) at (5,2.5) {};
\path let \p1=(neL0), \p2=(neRM), \p3=(\x1,\y2), \p4=($(\p3)+(0,10pt)$), \p5=($(neRM)+(0,-10pt)$) in
  [draw=red,fill=yellow,opacity=0.9] (\p3) -- (\p4) -| (neRM) -- cycle ;

\node (neL0) at (1,5) {};
\node (neRM) at (5,3.5) {};
\path let \p1=(neL0), \p2=(neRM), \p3=(\x1,\y2), \p4=($(\p3)+(0,10pt)$), \p5=($(neRM)+(0,-10pt)$) in
  [draw=red,fill=yellow,opacity=0.9] (\p3) -- (\p4) -| (\p2) -- cycle ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The two paths should be identical - however, when I compile, I get this output:

[image: test03.png]

... that is, the below (first) path, has its fill broken - and the reason for that apparently is using `(neRM)` in the path construction, instead of `(\p2)`.

Not sure - is this supposed to work this way with `let` path construction commands - or is this a bug?

Comment: Nodes don't represent coordinates. You need `(neRM.center)` otherwise it is not registered as a coordinate in the stream. Or change (neRM) to `\coordinate`

Comment: Thanks for that @percusse - makes sense; feel free to post that as an answer; will accept it ... Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used in the stream a node name finishes the path up to it and starts a new one if the path continues. This is due to the fact that if a node has a border shape the point on the border is computed and connected to that point, then, another point on the border is computed and remaining path continues from there.

In your case the path stops at the top of the node and closed from there. So you need to explicitly add another coordinate either making the node a coordinate or explicitly refering to an anchor of the node. You can also simplify the syntax a bit to get the same effect.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw] (neL0) at (1,4) {lo};
\node[draw] (neRM) at (5,2.5) {rm};
%\path let \p1=(neL0|-neRM), \p2=($(\p1)+(0,10pt)$) in
  [fill=yellow,opacity=0.9] (\p1) -- (\p2) -| (neRM) --  cycle;

%\draw (neL0|-neRM) --++(0,10pt) -| (neRM) --  cycle; % This is the same as above

\fill[yellow] (neL0|-neRM) --++(0,10pt) -| (neRM.center) --  cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @percusse - very nice explanation (wasn't aware of that with the border shapes); cheers!